# drag and drop reorder images in a div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm building a web application where users can add upload image from their devices, I want them to be able to reorder these images using drag and drop to enable rearrangement. I tried using JQuery and javascript but it seems I can't get it right. Thanks in advance.

```js
 document.querySelector("#files").addEventListener("change", (e) => {
            if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
                const files = e.target.files;
                const output = document.querySelector("#result");
                const div = document.createElement("ul");
                for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                    if (!files[i].type.match("image")) continue;
                    const picReader = new FileReader();
                    picReader.addEventListener("load", function (event) {
                        const picFile = event.target;
                        const div = document.createElement("div");
                        div.setAttribute("draggable", "true");
                        div.setAttribute("class", "image_div");
                        div.style.width = "60px";
                        div.style.height = "60px";
                        div.style.marginLeft = "10px";
                        div.style.flexShrink = "0";
                        div.style.overflowY = "hidden";
                        div.innerHTML = `<img class="thumbnail" src="${picFile.result}" title="${picFile.name}"/>`;
                        output.appendChild(div);
                    })
                    picReader.readAsDataURL(files[i]);
                }
            } else {
                alert("Your browser does not support File API")
            }


        })
```

```css
#result {
        display: flex;
        background-color: yellow;
        margin-top: -60px;
        margin-left: 60px;
        height: 65px;
        width:100%;
        overflow-x: auto;
        overflow-y: hidden;   
    }

    .thumbnail {
        /*height: 60px;
        width: 60px;
        border-radius: 6px;*/
        height: 60px;
        width: 60px;
        object-fit:cover;
        border-radius: 6px;
    }
```

```html
<div id="result">

        </div>
```

[result now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z77aU.png)

Comment: The code sample you provided results in an error here on StackOverflow (click the "Run code snippet" button to see what I mean). Please provide a reproducible example to make it easier for people to help you debug your issue. Unrelated sidenote: you may want to consider changing your username since it's an acronym with a deeply negative connotation in a US (English) context.

Comment: Abandon JQuery...just use dom apis going forward.